# Ember.js RESTAdapter requires PUT to response with JSON

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

When I do `this.get('store').commit();` in `PostController` to sent PUT with JSON like:

```
{
    "post": {
         "text": "lorem ipsum",
         "something": 23
    } 
}
```

and response from API is just status code 200 then `Post` model `isError` is true...

I have to response with the same body as request payload or at least with `{"post": {}}` to satisfy `Post` model and get `isLoaded` property `true` again.

**I'm wondering why Ember.js require PUT response to contains JSON data?**

`POST` requires JSON response (with backend generated IDs etc) but what is the reason for `PUT` to carry extra information and increase bandwidth? Especially that Ember.js even won't use them, empty JSON with `post` property is enough...

Comment: Did you get an answer for this.. if so please share.

Comment: Any clue on this yet? Why do we need to send entire data in the response? It takes a lot of bandwidth in case of larger documents.

Answer (score 3):

A good overview of the expected format for get, put, etc. can be found here: http://blog.embed.ly/post/50012690904/ember-at-embedly-tutorial-models-and-ember-data

It is indeed so that you need to return the complete object after a put (I have no insight into the reasons why this is so ...).

You can monitor this by using Ember extensions for Chrome. In the data tab, you will see that upon creation of a new record the properties are filled when you start entering data in for example an input field. When clicking save (transaction.commit), you enter inFlight status and at that moment you have a model with all fields completed, except the id field. When the server response comes in, the model is updated with the received data: the id property is completed and all other properties are overwritten with the data received from the server. If you thus only return the id, the other properties will be cleared out ...

Answer (score 1):

RESTAdapter has been modified since then. It's now checking the http code of the response.

- 200 for loading the returned model
- 204 for OK from the server without content

More details are in this [thread](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model/pull/340)